# graphical diff/patch file viewer

Tags: software-development, diff

There are numerous GUI diff tools, such as meld, kdiff3, kompare and others. However, it seems that all of these expect to get the input files and compare them, rather than allowing you to supply your *own* difference, from another source, and displaying that.

Are there diff viewers which accept .diff outputs of the actual diff utility?

**Requirements:**

- GUI (not text mode)
- OS: supports GNU/Linux
- Gratis
- Free software

Comment: I'm not sure what you want - Do you only have the diff file? The diff + the original?

Comment: @MichaelKohne: For the sake of discussion, I have _just_ the diff file.

Comment: Although I might also have one of the versions, and the diff, but not the other one. It's just not what I asked about.

Comment: I've never actually seen such a tool. If you have the original and the diff, then you could apply the diff (using patch), and then use a visual diffing tool to compare the before and after versions. FAR from ideal, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

It's not great, but if you use an editor with syntax coloring, you could at least make the diffs EASIER to read. This is what Notepad++ produces on Windows, as an example of what's possible:

[image]

Comment: It's not that I don't appreciate the suggestion, but obviously an editor is what I've been doing for lack of a more appropriate tool. (Well, either that or colordiff).